# what is .bashrc - How to find the startup file - putty

Tags: linux, putty

I was going over this [article](http://ericmason.net/2010/04/putty-ssh-windows-clipboard-integration/) and it states in step 3

```
Add the following to your .bashrc (or the appropriate startup file for your shell)  To use it immediately, be sure to type “source .bashrc”
```

Any idea on how I could know what my startup file is ? I am using putty ?

Comment: I am not sure I understood the question but .bashrc file is in the home directory of the user /home/<user>/.bashrc, where <user> is the user you use logging in.

Comment: if you're using putty, you'll need to put `source .bashrc` in /home/<user>/.bash_profile or /home/<user>/.profile too, and then it will run when you log in

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Once you use putty to SSH into your server, you can run "ls -al .bashrc" and it should show you the file, edit this with an editor you know, if none, then use vi like this "vi .bashrc".

Go to where you need to edit the file and type in "i" to put vi in Insert mode.  Next type in your text.  Once you are done press the escape button and ":wq", no quotes for the i or :wq.

Next you can source it by typing "source .bashrc" and the setting you added should be part of your BASH shell environment now.

Comment: It's probably better to try *nano* or *pico* before *vi*, if OP just wants the changes done instead of starting a project to learn a new editor...

Answer (score 14):

The [`.bashrc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) is a file which is called by bash before on each start of a new interactive shell. The file can be used to setup the environment, export variables, create aliases and functions and more...

There are usually multiple instances of that file. One per system and one per user to allow system wide configuration but also customization by users ( users bashrc will be sourced after the system wide bashrc and can overwrite things). I suggest to add the lines to your user's bashrc first. The file is located in your home folder. Type:

```
vi $HOME/.bashrc
```

in order to edit the file. If you aren't familiar with the `vi` editor you can choose an editor of your choice like `nano`, `mcedit` or even a GUI text editor, but mind that a GUI editor's file dialog may hide the file because it's name starts with a `.`

Once you managed to edit the file, start a new connection or simply type

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

in order to parse the file

Answer (score 3):

A path which will work with any bash shell regardless of operating system (macOS/Linux/BSD etc.) is:

```
~/.bashrc
```

Comment: What is "this"? How should this code you posted answer the question where that file is found?

Comment: @NicoHaase 's concerns addressed with most recent edit

Answer (score 1):

check your home directory ...because it exists in user's home directory.

check ***/home/username/*** on your terminal if you are using RHEL or CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

`.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are bash config files (bash shell script) that bash runs(execute) whenever it is started interactively. It initializes an interactive (non-login) shell session and the config is read from these files `$HOME/.bashrc`

.bashrc is a standard hidden  file located in your home directory.It determines the behaviour of interactive shells.
.bashrc runs on every interactive shell launch.If you say:  $bash

For login shells, the config is read from these files:

- `/etc/profile` (always sourced)
- `$HOME/.bash_profile` (the rest of these files are checked in order until one is found,then no other are read)
- `$HOME/.bash_login`
- `$HOME/.profile`

For example: I added an echo to my .bashrc and .bash_profile files and whenever I called `bash` or `bash -l` command in terminal it showed me the echo.